# Is dd command in linux faster than single character reading functions

Tags: linux, dd, c

I need to extract some content of different length at different offset from a file.
I would like to know whether to use dd command or simple character reading functions like `fgetc`

Comment: Wait let me guess on the one hand we have one c function in the current process and on the other hand we have dd which has to be started as a complete independent process, load it's binary and perform linking, start execution, parse command-line options, ...

Comment: @Robert,are you implying that creating a process takes more time anyway than calling some library function, but i think dd can read a block (of require size) a time,so i was not sure which is best

Comment: I have written a program using read and write system calls by using offsets and lengths but the file created is not same as  file created by dd, does dd does anything extra?

Comment: dd is just a software developer by smart people which uses the available API in an optimized way. We are talking about computers hence there is no magic. Why don't you just check the source code of dd how it works and learn how to read data the better way?

Comment: I checked , it uses same `read` and `write` calls with lots of combinations and characters sets checked

Comment: I have checked with the help of `gettimeofday` dd command takes more time than reading bytes and creating a part of file.